# Is "have" a copular verb

Tags: verbs

I wonder if *have* is also considered as a copular verb beside *be*. The reason is that *have* can sometimes be used as state of being like *be*. For example, we say "he has a degree in linguistics", which is the same as "he is a linguistics graduate".

Comment: *HAVE* is not a copular verb because it takes a direct object. Copular verbs take a subject complement.

Comment: But "be" also have a direct object

Comment: No, *BE*s take a subject complement: #1 "He is a good person", #2 "he is good". Note that the adjective "good" complements *BE* in #2. Direct objects must be noun phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand what a copular is. Downing & Locke (2006) gives the following definition:

> Copular verbs, a type of intransitive, require a Subject Complement. Only verbs capable of being used as copulas can be used in this way.

Copular verbs do not take direct objects as other lexical transitive verbs do, such as *HAVE*. *BE*, for example, takes a Subject Complement as in:

1. He is a good person
2. He is good

Note that Objects must be noun phrases, which is not the case in #2.* Gerund-participial clauses can function as an object but only when it's the predicand of a predicative complement as in "I find talking to Max rather stressful".

---

*<sub>'A good person' is not an object either; it cannot be promoted to subject in the passive clause.</sub>

Comment: How do you feel about promoting the object of "have" to subject in a passive clause:  'A degree in linguistics is had.'  That is such a bad use of the passive that it borders on being as ungrammatical as 'A linguistics graduate is been'.

Comment: @James K There are many exceptions to passivization even if the verb takes a direct object. Eg. You do not normally say "Jim was wanted by John to write a letter to the mayor", but you say "John wanted Jim to write a letter the mayor". What's important here is a subject complement can be realized by either a noun phrase or an adjective phrase, while an object has a be a noun phrase.

Comment: I don't agree. "Socrates is a man"  is perfectly OK, however, "is" has a direct object "man" which is a noun

Comment: @herme of course the sentence is OK. But "a man" is not an object since it cannot be promoted to subject in the passive clause and can be substituted by an adjective (cf. 'Socrates is manly'). All you need to understand is that an object and a subject complement are different.

Comment: Why do we need such things like subject complement? Now I simply give up copular verb and use state of being verbs that include “have”

Comment: @herme We need because a subject complement does not behave like an object whatsoever. For example, 1. it takes no article when the noun refers to a person who is assigned with a particular role: eg. "Trump is president of the United States"; 2. It cannot be promoted to subject in the passive clause: eg. *"president of the United States is been" ; 3. It may be realized by an adjective phrase: eg. "I feel tired" (cf. *'I have tired').

Comment: @herme Unique role can only be assigned to complements. You don't say *I met president of the United States*. I told you *a good person* is a complement. A complement cannot be promoted to subject. See Huddleston & Pullum (2005:75). Do you get it?

Comment: But "have" does not take a direct object either. For example, "he has a degree in linguistics" can not be converted to passive voice like "a degree in linguistics is had by him".

Comment: @herme Read my reply to James K.